# Refreshing a component bind to request-scoped bean

Tags: jsf, binding, primefaces, request, dashboard

Does anyone have a solution for such a problem:

In my app I'm using a complex, programmatically build dashboard based on the primefaces dashboard. To overcome problems with nonunique id's of the panels building the dashboard, I'm binding this component to a request-scoped bean. I'd also like to rebuild the dashboard based on some changable parameters after clicking a commandButton.

The problem is, that the getter for the dashboard is fired in the Apply Request Values phase, way before the actionListener of the commandButton is fired (in the Invoke Application phase). So, although the dashboard is rebuild eventually, it's not beeing refreshed in the rendered response.

On the other hand, if I try to set immediate attribute of the button to true, the actionListener is fired in the Apply Request Values phase, but still after the getter. Than the lifecycle goes directly to the Render Response phase, and the outcome is the same.

Anyone?

---

Thank you for the answer. Let me add a bit detail to my problem.

I store a model of a sports tournament as a property of a session scoped bean. It goes like this: the bean has a property "tournament". This class has a list of groups, each with it's table of matches. The idea was to use three different programmatically built components as renderers of this tournament model.

The dashboard would be used for drag-and-drop edition of contestant placement in groups. For viewing match tables and editing their matches I use a tab panel, with panel grid for every table. Finally, I use a panel grid to show a tournament tree. Every of those three components render some part of the model for the user to edit.

Since the model (and therefore those rendering components) are dynamically build depanding on chosable parameters like number of groups for example, i had a problem with id uniqnes when binding them to a session-scoped bean. So I bound them to a request scoped bean. With every request changing the model (mostly ajax) I wanted to rerender those components depending on the parameters set by the user (also stored in the session scoped bean).

The problem is, that when I rebuild the model in the invoke application phase (in a action listener fired by the "rebuild-my-model" button), the components bound to a request-scoped bean have already been "get-ed" from the bean (or so it seems), and they do not refresh on the page.

I would be very gratefull for a clue to what i'm doing wrong, and perhaps a suggestion, if the approach mentioned above is completelly stupid :)

Comment: Problem solved, thanks to BalusC. The idea was to set a new model for the components with every request, not trying to manually create and substitute them in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The problem is, that the getter for the dashboard is fired in the Apply Request Values phase, way before the actionListener of the commandButton is fired*

I'm not sure why exactly that forms a problem for you. Perhaps you're incorrectly doing business logic in the getter method instead of in the action listener method? Or perhaps you're manually creating the component instead of referencing the JSF-created one and thus always overridding the one in the JSF view?

A proper JSF getter method basically look like this:

```
public UIComponent getDashboard() {
    return dashboard;
}
```

It should *not* contain any other line of code. The same applies to the setter method by the way. Any actions wherein you need to manipulate the component's children needs to be done in an action(listener) method, not in a getter/setter method.